# Extracting member's first name from member table using results from another table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include 'dbFunctions.php';
$courseid = $_GET['Course_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE Course_id=".$courseid."";
$arrCourse = executeSelectQuery($query);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM course_member WHERE Course_id=".$courseid."";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query2) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

HTML body:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

      <?php echo $row['member_id']
      ?>

      <?php
}
?>
```

this correctly prints the results of the member id that is involved in the selected course, however, i want to extract the first_name using the result generated that belong to another table called member.

been trying all the join queries but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to read up on the JOIN operation in SQL.  The following query will return all the data you seem to need, from a single query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course
INNER JOIN course_member ON course.id = course_member.course_id
INNER JOIN member ON member.id = course_member.member_id
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see

```
$sql="select last_name from course_member 
join member on course_member.member_id = member.member_id
where course_member.Course_id = ".$courseid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a guess here at your table defs...

```
$query2 = "SELECT m.first_name, cm.* FROM course_member cm join member m on m.id = cm.member_id WHERE Course_id=".$courseid."";
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much! that definitely helped me in a bit and clarified things for me esp using the join clause! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the member name and you are not much interested with the id then you can merge it into a single query

```
 $query = SELECT fName from member WHERE id = (SELECT member_id FROM course_member WHERE Course_id=$courseid);
```